# Most efficient way to draw rectangle to screen

Tags: c++, windows, drawing

Essentially I want a **border-less, black** window which I can set the location and size of./

I then want to draw a filled white polygon given four points.

I say efficient, as I am currently using OpenCV to draw which I believe is every inefficient. I want to be able to change the points and have it redraw with new points at least 30fps.

My target platform is Windows with C++.

Does anyone know the quickest way to achieve this, maybe with a small library?

Comment: Direct2D/DirectDraw and OpenGL come pretty close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this will be to use DirectX. You can create, resize, and reposition the window with the Windows API and render into it with DirectX. DX has a much more accessible API than OpenGL, because OGL is full of implicit globals and weak typing, and the support libraries like GLUT are terrible C hackery as well, whereas DX is easy to whip up RAII with a couple of custom deleters and is object-orientated.

You can also use, if on Vista or later, Direct2D, which is more designed for simple 2D rendering.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use `openGl` eg via the `GLUT` library.

Comment: +1 for OpenGL+GLUT (though you'd probably want to use freeglut by now). You can hardly draw a polygon much easier than this, plus with hardware acceleration. This is little more than a dozen lines of code alltogether. Alternatively, GLFW could be used to the same effect, also dead simple.